# Show $c_{00} \ni (x_n)_{n=1}^\infty \mapsto \big(\frac{x_n}{n+1}\big)_{n=1}^\infty \in c_{00}$ is a surjection and compute its norm

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, convergence-divergence, operator-theory

Let's define
$$A: (x_n)_{n=1}^\infty \in c_{00} \mapsto \Big(\frac{x_n}{n+1}\Big)_{n=1}^{\infty} \in c_{00}.$$

where $c_{00} = \{(x_n)_{n=1}^{\infty}:\exists {n_0}, \, \forall{n>n_0}, \, x_n = 0\}$

I want to prove that $A$ is continuous bijection and to calculate $\|A\|$.

**My work so far:**

- **Injection**

$A(x_n) = A(y_n) \Leftrightarrow (\frac{x_n}{n+1}) = \frac{y_n}{n+1} \Leftrightarrow x_n = y_n$ ok

- **Surjection**

> Question: $\forall{y_n \in c_{00}}\exists{x_n \in c_{00}}:y_n=A(x_n)$?

$$y_n = \frac{x_n}{n+1} \Leftrightarrow y_n(n+1) = x_n$$

Okay, we found for any $y_n \in c_{00}$ representation by $A(x_n)$.

- **Norm calculation**

$$\|A\| = \sup\{|A(x_n)|, x_n \in c_{00}, \|x\| \le 1\}$$
$$|A(x_n)| = \left|\frac{x_n}{n+1}\right| \le \frac{1}{n + 1}$$

And here I have intuitive problem. Can the norm of the operator be dependent on $n$? My intuition suggests me that it should be a real number, not a sequence. However the supremum can be easily obtained by sequence:

$$
y_n^k=
\begin{cases}
\frac{1}{n+1} & \mathrm{for} \; n < k\\
0 & \mathrm{for} \; n \ge k \\
\end{cases}
$$

then $y_n^k \rightarrow \frac{1}{n+1}$ as $k \rightarrow \infty$

> My question is: Are my proofs of bijection are correct as well as my norm calculation?

Comment: what is $c_{00}$?

Comment: @Axel [$c_{00}$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sequence_space#c,_c0_and_c00)

Comment: Thanks for your question. I updated my post ;))

Comment: For the norm you have that $\|A(x)\|_{\infty}=\sup_n|x_n/(n+1)|\leq \sup_n|x_n|/2=\frac{1}{2}\|x\|_{\infty}$. This tells you that the norm of $A$ is bounded above by $1/2$. You can use $x=(1,0,0,...)$ to show that the bound is attained.

Comment: @plop : you can write this as an answer

Comment: The linearity of $A$ and the fact $\Vert A (x) \Vert \leq \frac{1}{2} \Vert x \Vert$ also proves that $A$ is continuous.

Answer (score 1):

You have that
$$
|A(x_n)|\leq \frac1{n+1},
$$
but you want the norm on $c_{00}$ so now you have to take the supremum. Thus
$$
\|A\|\leq\sup\Big\{\frac1{n+1}:\ n\in\mathbb N\Big\}=\frac12.
$$
The inequality becomes an equality if $x_1=1$, so $\|A\|=\frac12$.